# Pandas GroupBy on large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains 150 columns. Out of 150 , there are 15 columns of type string and the rest are all floats.

The dataframe contains identical records for combinations of 15 string columns, and the values in rest can differ. I wanted to do *groupby* on these 15 string columns and do a sum of all float columns.

How do I do this easily in Python without specifying name of each columns in the *groupby* statement since the dataframe is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint for your work. You can filter the columns of string type with this code.

```
string_columns = list()    
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtypes == 'O':
        string_columns.append(col)
```

Finally the string_columns will contains column names with Object data type which can be used for your groupby function.

Comment: this helped to get what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension 1st filter the columns with type object type and use the cols in your group by function

```py
cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype == np.object]
df.groupby(cols).sum()
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24116546).

Comment: used the groupby syntax .. Thanks

Comment: I did notice that after groupby , no of records remain the same before and after.

Comment: this could happen if group of columns (cols) has unique values